# Grouped Frequency Bars in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing

I'm trying to produce a bar graph with frequencies of multiple groups. I tried using geom_bar() but I keep running into "Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic." I have one line for each participant, with age (2 categories), condition (2 categories), and their performance (0 or 1). From what I read on the manual and in pretty much everywhere online, if I use

```
bar<-ggplot(data, aes(age, performance, fill = condition)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

I should get what I want ([which is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D20Qz.png)), but instead I get the error and I can't figure out what I'm missing. Isn't the geom_bar() supposed to give count by default? When I use stat="identity" I get full bars like so: [how it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIsYU.png).
Please help! Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

EDITED:
Here's my actual data:

```
structure(list(ageyears = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L), MatrixLabels = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), Mat_sort_pass_fail = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("ageyears", 
"MatrixLabels", "Mat_sort_pass_fail"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 
104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 
115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 
126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 
137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 
148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 
159L, 160L, 197L, 198L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 
207L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of geom_bar :

> By default, geom_bar uses stat="count" which makes the height of the
>   bar proportion to the number of cases in each group (or if the weight
>   aethetic is supplied, the sum of the weights). If you want the heights
>   of the bars to represent values in the data, use stat="identity" and
>   map a variable to the y aesthetic.

In your case you should use the height as your sum of your performance, since you have a summarized data , so the ggplot should use `stat = identity`

**EDIT** After OP pasted the dput:

You need to first summarize your data, I am assuming the `df` is your dataframe, you can use anything to do the summarization, I am using `data.table` and baseR aggregate, you can pick either of them to do it as below:

```
###1. base R aggregate

 df <- aggregate(Mat_sort_pass_fail ~ ageyears + MatrixLabels, data=df1 ,sum)
df$perc <- df$Mat_sort_pass_fail/sum(df$Mat_sort_pass_fail)
names(df) <- c("age","condition","performance","percentage")



###2. sumarization using data.table
library(data.table)

dt <- setDT(df)
dt1 <- dt[,list(Performance = sum(Mat_sort_pass_fail)),by=c("ageyears","MatrixLabels")]
dt1[,perc:=Performance/sum(Performance)] ##percentage within column

df <- data.frame(dt1)
names(df) <- c("age","condition","performance","percentage")


library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

ggplot(df, aes(x = condition ,y=performance)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(age)),stat="identity",position = "dodge") +
  ggtitle("Matrix Sort Performance") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")

###In case you need the percentage run the below code:
ggplot(df, aes(x = condition ,y=percentage)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(age)),stat="identity",position = "dodge") +
  ggtitle("Matrix Sort Performance") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So, when I use stat=identity, I get a weird graph (the second link I attached to my original question). What do you mean when you say my data is summarised? I have one line for each participant, I'm editing the question to add an example.

Comment: @GalPodjarny, Are you sure your performance would always be 0 and 1 because it seems to me that to receive the desirable graph it has to have a continuous form rather than a dichotomous form. I think when you summarized your table for condition and age your performance should be summed on its values or it could be just counts but it can't be a dichotomous form.

Comment: this particular variable is a pass/fail variable, so it is dichotomous. The graph I want is taken from that same data done with excel, I was just hoping to re-produce it in R so that the graphs are all done consistently. I haven't summarised any of the data, I gave ggplot the dataframe as shown in my example. Any idea why ggplot behaves the way it does? :)

Comment: @GalPodjarny , can you do a dput on a dataframe , dput(df) and paste it on your question.

Comment: @GalPodjarny, I have added the code in case you need percentages rather than sums

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . @GalPodjarny , Please mark this as an answer. The green tick

Answer (score -1):

Normally it calculates frquencies from your data. If your data is already grouped try below:

```
+ geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `geom_col()` as an alias for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

You also had what I think is wrong aes mapping.

I mimicked some data based on the graph you posted:

```r
df <- data.frame(age = factor(rep(4:5, each = 2), labels = c('4-Years-Olds', '5-Years-Olds')),
                 performance = c(48,37,65,65),
                 condition = factor(c(1,2,1,2), labels = c('No Label', 'Label')))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
    geom_col(aes(condition, performance, fill = age), position = 'dodge') +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('skyblue', 'darkolivegreen1'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So, do I need to aggregate the data then? To create a table with the number of children scoring 1? Because that's what I see in your code... I was hoping I can get a direct graph from the vector?

Comment: It's of course possible to work with not aggregated data, that's just what I understood from your question. Share your data with ‘dput(data)‘ to have an appropriate answer